# Error Missing 'Before Statement' - @import

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm getting an error in Firebug Web Developer when loading my site:

```
Error: missing ; before statement
Source File: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css
Line: 10, Column: 1
Source Code:
@import "jquery.ui.base.css";
```

*Here's that full file:*

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI CSS Framework 1.8.19
 *
 * Copyright 2012, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming
 */
@import "jquery.ui.base.css";
@import "jquery.ui.theme.css";
```

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Are you importing a CSS file as a script perhaps?

Comment: this [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/another-missing-before-statement-problem-but-other-posts-have-not-helped-me-any) might help

Comment: @b_dubb that's a good link for a weird problem, but this is about a CSS file generating JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only reason you would get JavaScript errors for a CSS file is if you are loading the CSS as JavaScript.

This may sound patronising, but are you maybe doing:

```
<script src="jquery.ui.base.css"></script>
```

If so, it should be changed to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.base.css" />
```

Of course, this is an easier mistake to make if you are using some jQuery import thing instead, but we'd need to see more of your source code to determine that.

Comment: in my case, i was loading scripts and css dynamically and this was my problem :) thank you